# Win 7 and .bat files

Tags: windows-7, batch

Does Win 7 support .bat files like WinXP? For example, will Win 7 run the following file:

```
Start "" "C:\Documents and Settings\HDSF Staff\My Documents\My Dropbox\Texter\texter.exe"
```

Comment: In XP, .bat files run on command.com, which is a lot slower than cmd.exe, which runs .cmd files. Support for 16-bit apps is gone in 7, but the distinction and speed difference may remain. If you don't need legacy features, .cmd is recommended, in general.

Comment: How did you determine that command.com commands are slower compared to cmd.exe commands ? I do not concur with that assumption.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Try it out yourself! All versions of Windows do (actually batch file support comes from DOS times).

Comment: +1 :: "Start" is also way cooler (functionally) in Windows 7 than it was in DOS days. :)

Comment: What is +1 :: "Start"??

Comment: @techie007: I'll say! DOS didn't have start.exe!

Comment: @Anonymous: Windows doesn't have either. "start" is an internal command: it is hardcoded in command.com (DOS/Windows 9x) or cmd.exe (Windows NT series: NT,2k,XP,Vista,7)

Comment: @whitequark: I'm looking at a start.exe in win95/win95_14.cab on the Windows 95B install disk and in win98/WIN98_42.cab on the Windows 98 upgrade install disk. It didn't exist in DOS 6.22. It was rolled into cmd.exe for Windows NT. It did exist in Windows 9x.

Comment: @Anonymous: Ok, necromancer, so you are right! [checking my Win95 iso image...]

Comment: Wow, maybe it wasn't in DOS. I used it extensivly in my BBS days, but now that you freaks remind me, it wasn't really until the later Win9x days. Like whitequark said, still command.com though, so you'll have to forgive my memory. ;)

Comment: @jruday: "Start" is the utility your using to launch the file in your original question.  Try "Start /?" at a command prompt.

Comment: You do not need any start. The command will just launch just as-is in path format.